# Calculating a mode

Tags: arrays, count, mode

I know this is how you calculate a mode for an array of data.

```
public double mode() {
    int maxValue=0, maxCount=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            if (a[j] == a[i])
                ++count;
            }
        }
        if (count > maxCount) {
            maxCount = count;
            maxValue = a[i];
        }
    }
return maxValue; }
```

I have a problem when there are multiple values that can be modes. So I want to output (return Double.NaN;) if there are multiple values that are a mode. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition for when the count is equal:

```
if (count > maxCount) {
  maxCount = count;
  maxValue = a[i];
} else if (count == maxCount && maxValue != a[i]) {
  maxValue = Double.NaN;
}
```

Demo (in Javascript): http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/xWvAV/

Comment: This didn't work. It outputs NaN even if there is a one value that can be a mode or there are multiple values.

Comment: @AzariaGebo: You are right. Each value is counted the number of times that it occurs, so it occurs the same number of times as itself. You have to check if it's the same value also. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had spent a good amount of time trying to figure this out. You helped a lot.